# nest to get list-columns of vectors rather than list-column of data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

`tidyr::nest()` creates a list-column of data frames/tibbles:

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% nest(data = c(-Species))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Species    data             
#>   <fct>      <list>           
#> 1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 4]>
#> 2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 4]>
#> 3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 4]>
```

This is of course useful in lots of cases. In other cases, what I want is to do the same sort of implicit summarizing operation, but instead of creating a single list-column of tibbles, I want to turn each selected column into a list-column of *vectors*.

What I'm looking for can be accomplished by following `nest()` with `unnest_wider()`:

```
iris %>% nest(data = c(-Species)) %>%
  unnest_wider(data)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>       <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>  <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>
#> 1 setosa             [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
#> 2 versicolor         [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
#> 3 virginica          [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
```

It can also be accomplished by a more explicit summarizing operation:

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), vctrs::list_of))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   Species    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#>   <fct>       <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>  <list<dbl>> <list<dbl>>
#> 1 setosa             [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
#> 2 versicolor         [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
#> 3 virginica          [50]        [50]         [50]        [50]
```

But both of these seem a little unwieldly, and I'm wondering if there is a more parsimonious or more standard way of doing this in `tidyr` or related tidyverse packages.

Comment: This is equivalent to `as_tibble(aggregate(.~Species, iris, list))`. The `as_tibble` ensures the prinitng is as shown above. I do not believe there is a functio to do this. You will have to use the weirdly looking ways you have above.

Answer (score 0):

This saves about 30 characters typed :

```
iris |>
 group_by(Species) |> 
 summarise_all(list)
```